# Getting parts of a path in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of people as follows:

```
people = ['personA', 'personB', 'personC'];
```

I want to be able to display a page about the person based on the url. For example, `localhost:3000/people/personA` would direct me to a page about personA.

How do I do so without having to specify the following multiple times for each team member? Is there a way I can grab the part after '/people/'?

```
  app.get('/people/personA', (req, res) => {
     // render view for personA
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it with a parameter in the url. You can add a parameter using **:param_here** and get its value using `req.params.param_here` Like so:

```
app.get('/people/:person', (req, res) => {
    var person = req.params.person; // Variable telling you which person to show
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
app.get('/people/:person', funcation (req, res){
    res.render("views/"+req.params.person+".html"); 
  }
});
```